# SettingWithCopyWarning Error in Pandas when using groupby and transform

Tags: pandas

I received error

`SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

on my code `df['mean'] = df.groupby('col1').transform('mean')`
I want to add the calculation as a new column.

I understood the error message and learnt that I need to use `.loc` to solve the issue but I don't know how to include `.loc` into my current code.

Comment: Like commented in your other question, Can you post the **actual** code where you define your `df`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
df.loc[:, 'mean'] = df.groupby('col1').transform('mean')
```